# AssertEqual returning False when, from Observation is True

Tags: python, unit-testing, equality, sudoku

I'm currently revising for an exam, for which there is a test script given by the professor.
The question concerns the game Sodoku; in this section, I have to return all non-zero values of a row of values to the Sudoku table (represented by a 2D array) as a set.

```
def get_values_from_row(puzzle, row): 
    rowVal = []
    try:
        for i in puzzle[row]:
            if i != 0:
                rowVal.append(i)
    except IndexError: 
        print('Invalid Row')
    if len(rowVal) == 0: 
        return rowVal
    else: 
        rowVal = set(rowVal) 
        print(rowVal)
        return(rowVal)
```

here is the Sudoku board

```
sudoku1 = [[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
       [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
       [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],
       [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
       [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
       [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
       [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]]
```

When I run the function for row 0 I get {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} as expected. However, when I run the test script returns a fail.

This is the relevant code in the test script:

```
import unittest


class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_get_values_from_row(self):
        sudoku1 = [
               [5, 3, 4, 0, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
               [6, 7, 0, 0, 9, 5, 0, 4, 8],
               [1, 9, 8, 0, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7],
               [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
               [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
               [7, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
               [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
               [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
               [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]]

       self.assertEqual(sg.get_values_from_row(sudoku1, 0), set([6]))
```

`sg` is just what the script I'm editing is imported as. When I look at the log apparently `6` is not in the set, when I changed it to `3` the same thing happened. It looked like whatever the test value was it would be deleted from my returned list

```
Traceback (most recent call last):'
File "question_1_iii_test.py", line 23, in test_get_values_from_row'
self.assertEqual(sg.get_values_from_row(sudoku1, 0), set([6]))'
AssertionError: Items in the first set but not the second:'
1
2
3
4
5
7
8
9
Items in the second set but not the first:
6
```

**My question is:** Why does AssertEqual return false when it's clearly true?

Comment: I think your logic is backwards, you are effectively asking is `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9} == {6}`, which is clearly `False`. Are you wanting to check the sets are disjoint? Or do you want to know if it is a subset?

Comment: well I didn't write the test script; that's the issue I don't understand what exactly AssertEqual is trying to do; if it's saying  `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9} == {6}` there must be something wrong with the test script right? because what would that be testing when the question is asking to return a full set of values not just one

Comment: Are you sure that `get_values_from_row()` is supposed to return the used values and not the unused values - the test seems to imply it is supposed to return the unused values.

Comment: `The function
should return a list (as a set built-in type) containing all non-zero values in that row,
an empty list if the row is empty (i.e. contains only zeros).`  is the exact wording

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I contacted my professor and apparently, the test code was incorrect it was meant to be inverting the list so that the only number in the list was the one that was omitted in the row so in a way; we were all right

Answer (score 1):

The return value of the function is not same as `[6]`, so AssertEqual return false

```
sg.get_values_from_row(sudoku1, 0) = [5, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]
```

which is not equal to `[6]`

Comment: but why is 6 being omitted from the returned values in the test script only?

Comment: there's no `6` in the first row (0), `[5, 3, 4, 0, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],`

Comment: so why would I test for a 6 if it's not in the row? could this be some kind of reverse testing?

Comment: well. i think you missed some element from the first sodoku1 row(0) `               [5, 3, 4, 0, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],`. this row has a 6. So i think you need to test whether 6 is in the set or not.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably due to a datatype error. set([6]) will give a type() set while sudoku1 is a list and contains lists

```
[6]==set([6])
```

will return False